# ( sdonate) 1067 Invalid default value for 'expiretime' in /var/www/donate/install.php:

Tags: php, mysql

Error when running /install.php

```
[Sat Nov 10 20:43:26.241729 2018] [:error] [pid 25855] [client 108.162.237.55:35442] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\r\n                endcommands TEXT,\r\n                transactionid TEXT,\r\n      ' at line 9 in /var/www/donate/install.php:258\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/donate/install.php(258): PDO->exec('CREATE table tr...')\n#1 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/donate/install.php on line 258
```

Lines 239-260 of install.php:

```
if(tableExists($dbcon, 'transactions') === FALSE){
    $sql = "CREATE table transactions(
            id INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
            time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
            purchaser TEXT,
            usernametype TEXT,
            username TEXT,
            game TEXT,
            expires INT(1),
            expiretime ,
            endcommands TEXT,
            transactionid TEXT,
            package TEXT,
            packageid TEXT,
            paymentmethod TEXT,
            value DECIMAL(11,2),
            status TEXT,
            params TEXT);";
    $dbcon->exec($sql);
```

}

software: sdonate.com
not sure how to fix it, documentation shows no solutions.

what would be a solution?

Comment: I would make the cause for the error, `an error in your SQL syntax`, more prominently displayed, so whoever's answering this can see what type of error they need to look for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`expiretime` field does not have a data type, hence the syntax error. You need to provide the data type (probably datetime based on the name of the field).

Comment: This has got nothing to do with php, the sql is broken. You need to provide the appropriate **data type**, not just the default value. I can't tell you what the right data type is, I can only guess.

Comment: well `expiretime INT(11),` fixed it.

Comment: I'm not sure if int is the right data type for a field name as expiretime. Int is a valid data type for sure, but may cause issues later. You should contact the developer of this tool and ask him / her to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

got it, just had to change it to:

`expiretime INT(11),`